# Azure Web App HTTP ERROR 414 - Url too long request

Tags: angular, azure, .net-core

Our Dot Net Core 5 is hosted on Linux Azure Web App, which contains angular 12 web apps.

```
this.router.navigate([]).then((result) => {
            window.open('/flight/flight-book?flightdata=' + encodeURIComponent(this.encryptData(hiddenvalue)), '_blank');
        });
```

Now the above code is running on the browser getting an error - HTTP ERROR 414 - URL Too Long but running in localhost it is working fine.

We think that the azure web app is stopping this URL to render on the browser. Even on web.config we mention the below code but still not working.

```
<system.webServer>
    <!--   Here you have other settings related to handlers.-->
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="10485760" maxUrl="1000241" maxQueryString="3002768" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
```

Comment: What is the actual length of the URL generated using the expression `'/flight/flight-book?flightdata=' + encodeURIComponent(this.encryptData(hiddenvalue))` that causes the `414` error?

Comment: Yes, the length is a long encrypted string -- but running on localhost it is all good, only after deployment on azure web app getting HTTP 414.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved this by [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) API, finally, I can able to work with the long text value for multiple pages across the application.

```
localStorage.setItem("flightinfo", JSON.stringify(this.countries));//set value
localStorage.getItem('flightinfo' + paramGuid);//get value
```

It's working for me, Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Azure App Services for Linux run in a container so if you send a HTTP request to your App Service, it is first handled by a reverse proxy server on Azure outside of your control and afterwards the request is forwarded to your application in the container. You web.config has no effect on the reverse proxy and this is the component which will enforce the URL limit. I just tested it and it seems that the maximum query length which still gets accepted on Linux App Services is **8192 characters**.

On Windows App Services the limit is **2048 characters** by default, but here you can control the server directly and so a `web.config` like this...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <httpRuntime maxUrlLength="32768" maxQueryStringLength="32768" />
   </system.web>
   <system.webServer>
      <security>
         <requestFiltering>
            <requestLimits maxQueryString="32768" />
         </requestFiltering>
      </security>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

...will set the maximum URL length to 32768 characters.

That being said as you just experienced, sometimes browsers and servers will define URL or query string limits which you can't always control - it's better to **move longer data to the HTTP body.**